# Function that passes arguments to the next function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Is there a ramda function that takes function argument and passes it to the next function invoked in that scope?

I want to achieve something like this, without using an arrow function:

```
R.allPass([x => R.not(R.isEmpty(x)), R.isNil])(data)
```

It would probably look similar to this one:

```
const passArgument = (func, func2) => arg => func(func2(arg));

R.allPass([passArgument(R.not, R.isEmpty), R.isNil])(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`R.compose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) is the function you're after.

```
R.allPass([R.compose(R.not, R.isEmpty), R.isNil])(data)
```

There is also [`R.pipe`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe) for composing functions from left to right.

For this particular example you might also be interested in [`R.both`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#both) and [`R.complement`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#complement) which could be implemented as:

```
R.both(R.complement(R.isEmpty), R.isNil)
```

I'm not entirely sure whether you'd ever find something that is both `null`/`undefined` and non-empty though for this to ever evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Ahhh, it was too obvious! Thanks a lot!
Ps: yep, it was made up example